# cassandra cluster joining delay

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to install 3 cassandra using bosh release.I am getting error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Other bootstrapping/leaving/moving nodes detected, cannot bootstrap while cassandra.consistent.rangemovement is true
```

On searching in net i found that we need to put some delay when cluster joins.Let me know how to introduced delay. Do we have any attribute for this ?

```
- name: cassandra_seed
  templates:
  - name: cassandra
    release: cassandra
  - name: collectd
    release: metrics
  - name: logstash-shipper
    release: cassandra
  - name: consul
    release: consul
  instances: 1
  resource_pool: service-net-medium
  persistent_disk: 10240
  networks:
  - name: ccc-service-net
    default: [dns, gateway]
  properties:
    collectd:
      plugin_templates: [cassandra]
    cassandra:
        broadcast_address: 0.cassandra-seed.ccc-service-net.<%= $deployment_name %>.microbosh
    consul:
      bootstrap_expect: 0
      join_hosts: ["0.vault-consul.ccc-service-net.<%= $deployment_name %>.microbosh"]
      service:
        name: cassandra
      process:
        name: ps -ef |grep cassandra |grep -v grep || exit 2
      server: false
      default_recursor: 8.8.8.8
  update:
    serial: false
```

Error

```
root@9e3c9ac3-1832-48cf-a58c-3ef25ee17869:/var/vcap/sys/log/cassandra# vim  cassandra.stderr.log
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Other bootstrapping/leaving/moving nodes detected, cannot bootstrap while cassandra.consistent.rangemovement is true
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:584)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:855)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:725)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:625)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:366)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:581)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:710)
```